# Update nested object using REST API

Tags: rest, api

I have resource `Student` and 4 API endpoints:

```
POST: /students
GET: /students/{id}
PUT: /students/{id}
DELETE: /students/{id}
```

Now, I want to add new property `Address` as an object to `Student`:

```
class Student 
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public Address Address;
}
```

`Address` has property `Street` as an object too.

My question is, if I want to update only the `address` or `street`, would it be better to:

- Use update student API: provide all student properties even if they are not changed
- Create new endpoints `PUT: /students/{id}/address` and `PUT: /students/{id}/address/street`

Answer (score 2):

It depends how client friendly you want the API to be. I've recently seen an API that returns an object but in order to update a single field in the object the client has to call another endpoint to get extra information to add to the original object in order to PUT the updated one. I regard that as client unfriendly.

If a client `GET`s a `Student` and they get the full object `Id`, `Name`, `Address`, `Street` then I would expect `PUT: /students/{id}` to be able to handle a full object, updating fields that are different from the one in the database or wherever the object is stored. If the API gives the client a full object then the API should be client friendly and be able to accept a full object back rather than making the client deconstruct the object.

I wouldn't expect a client to have to extract an `Address` from the `Student`, then extract the `Street` from the Address and send that to `PUT: /students/{id}/address/street` if the API gave the client a full `Student` object in the first place.

The only downside to this approach is bandwidth. If a single letter in the Street changes the client has to `PUT` the entire `Student` object. So it really depends what the client is and what network it operates on. A REST client on the internet? Accept full objects. An embedded client on a resource constrained device? It may need to send fragments of the object but that leads to the REST endpoints matching the `Student` object hierarchy which to me is close coupling and not really recommended.